# Form validation by pure JS

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

I am a stuck on following issues:

1. How to add required error just once after first click on submit button? And not at any subsequent click after.
2. How can to start function (checkValid()) with RegExp validation only after first function (checkRequired()) implementation with required checking?
3. How to show every error after RegExp validation in its relative element? Now all errors are displayed in the last block with phone input.

Here is case on jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/SanchezMalina/hno7v4tf/35/

Or code here:

```js
// regexp pattern functions
    function validateEmail(email) {
      let re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email.toLowerCase());
    }

    function validatePhone(phone) {
      let re = /^[0-9]{7,20}$/;
      return re.test(phone.toLowerCase());
    }

    function validateName(name) {
      let re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9А]){3,50}$/;
      return re.test(name.toLowerCase());
    }

    let flag = false;

    // check required fields
    function checkRequired() {

      let notFilled = document.querySelectorAll('.is-required');

      notFilled.forEach(function (el) {

        if (el.value === '') {

          el.parentElement.classList.add('is-empty');

          addRequiredError();

        } else {

          el.parentElement.classList.remove('is-empty');

          removeRequiredError();

        }

      });

    }

    let formFields = document.querySelectorAll('.form__field');

    //add required error message
    function addRequiredError() {

      let errorRequiredMsg = document.createElement('div');
      errorRequiredMsg.classList.add('input-required');
      errorRequiredMsg.innerHTML = `<span> This field is required! </span>`;

      formFields.forEach( function (elem) {

        if (elem.classList.contains('is-empty')) {

          elem.appendChild(errorRequiredMsg);

        }

      });

    }

    //remove required error message
    function removeRequiredError() {

      let requiredErrorMsg = document.querySelectorAll('.form__field .input-required');

      requiredErrorMsg.forEach(function (elem) {

        elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);

      });

      flag = true;

    }

    //check validation inputs
    function checkValid() {

      let firstName = document.querySelector('#f-name');
      let lastName = document.querySelector('#l-name');
      let selectCountry = document.querySelector('.form__select');
      let phone = document.querySelector('#cell');
      let email = document.querySelector('#email');

      formFields.forEach(function () {

        if(!validateName(firstName.value) && !validateName(lastName.value) && !validatePhone(phone.value) && !validateEmail(email.value)) {

          firstName.parentElement.classList.add('is-error');
          lastName.parentElement.classList.add('is-error');
          selectCountry.parentElement.classList.add('is-error');
          phone.parentElement.classList.add('is-error');
          email.parentElement.classList.add('is-error');

          addValidError();

        } else {

          firstName.parentElement.classList.remove('is-error');
          lastName.parentElement.classList.remove('is-error');
          selectCountry.parentElement.classList.remove('is-error');
          phone.parentElement.classList.remove('is-error');
          email.parentElement.classList.remove('is-error');

          removeValidError();

        }

      });

    }

    //add invalid error message
    function addValidError() {

      let errorValidMsg = document.createElement('div');
      errorValidMsg.classList.add('input-error');
      errorValidMsg.innerHTML = `<span> Input is invalid! </span>`;

      formFields.forEach(function (elem) {

        if (elem.classList.contains('is-error')) {

          elem.appendChild(errorValidMsg);

        }

      });

      // for (let i = 0; i < formFields.length; i++) {
      //
      //   if (formFields[i].classList.contains('is-error')) {
      //
      //     formFields[i].appendChild(errorValidMsg);
      //
      //   }
      // }
    }

    //remove invalid error message
    function removeValidError() {

      let requiredErrorMsg = document.querySelectorAll('.input-error');

      requiredErrorMsg.forEach(function (elem) {

        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

      })
    }

    //form submit handler
    let formTrial = document.querySelector('.form__main');

    formTrial.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      checkRequired();

      console.log(flag);

      if(flag !== false) {

        checkValid();

      }

    });
```

```css
.form__main {
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 450px;
}

.form__field {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}

.form__field_select::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  right: 17px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.form__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  background: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.714;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form__input:focus ~ .form__label,
.form__input:valid ~ .form__label {
  top: 0;
  left: 45px;
  transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
  color: #000;
}

.form__input:focus ~ .form__label[for=cell],
.form__input:valid ~ .form__label[for=cell] {
  top: 0;
  left: 125px;
}

.form__input[type=tel] {
  padding-left: 125px;
}

.form__input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px white inset;
}

.form__label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50px;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #999999;
  line-height: 1.714;
}

.form__label[for=cell] {
  left: 135px;
}

.form__select {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 50px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 1.714;
}

.form__country-code {
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  left: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.form .btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.form .btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 20px #c5f833;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="form__main" novalidate>
  <div class="form__field">
    <i class="icon icon-user"></i>
    <input class="form__input is-required" id="f-name" type="text" required>
    <label class="form__label" for="f-name">First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form__field">
    <i class="icon icon-user"></i>
    <input class="form__input is-required" id="l-name" type="text" required>
    <label class="form__label" for="l-name">Last Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form__field">
    <i class="icon icon-envelop"></i>
    <input class="form__input" id="email" type="text" required>
    <label class="form__label" for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form__field form__field_select">
    <i class="icon icon-pin"></i>
    <select class="form__select" name="country">
      <option value="ro" selected>USA</option>
      <option value="ua">India</option>
      <option value="il">Spain</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form__field">
    <i class="icon icon-phone"></i>
    <span class="form__country-code">+10000</span>
    <input class="form__input" id="cell" type="tel" required>
    <label class="form__label" for="cell">Phone</label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn_lime">Try for free</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should use the Csontraint Validation API instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation  No need to re-invent the wheel.  Also, your e-mail address regex is very broken, and won't work for many domains.

Comment: Thank you @Brad! I will try.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
if( !el.parentElement.classList.contains('is-empty') ) {
    addRequiredError();
}
```

2)
not sure to understand the question

3)

```
function addValidError() {
    let errorValidMsg = document.createElement('div');
    errorValidMsg.classList.add('input-error');
    errorValidMsg.innerHTML = '<span> Input is invalid! </span>';
    formFields.forEach(function (elem) { // <-- here formFields is not defined
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
1) where I should to put this if statement?
2) I mean this:
"How can to start function (checkValid()) with RegExp validation only after first function (checkRequired()) implementation with required checking?"
3) Maybe you know how can I change it?